# Events on dynamic created elements

Tags: jquery

Please anyone who knows about the ThreeDubMedia jquery.event.drop. I am using code from the selection demo. Here's the link [ThreeDubMedia](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drop#demos)

I need the same drag-to-select functionality on dynamic elements.
For click events I just use jquery .on(). But I have no idea how to get the same effect with this code.

```
$('.layout-grid [class*=span]')
  .drop("start",function(){
     $( this ).addClass("click");
  })
  .drop("end",function(){
     $( this ).removeClass("click");     
  });
```

how can I trigger these functions on dynamic elements that match the selector?

Comment: You have to call those methods when the elements are created.

Comment: You should use event delegation mechanism ... check `on()` jquery method 2nd signature `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ] )` 
[here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: @FelixKling thanks a lot, I was trying to do the same thing but in the wrong place, you basically answered my question in one sentence.

Comment: Apparently you can use event delegation, as Mohammad Adil pointed out. So in this case you can make use of it, but in general you have to call plugin method after you created the element(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the link you provided -- *This plugin also supports "live" event delegation*

Use this :

```
.on("drop",".layout-grid [class*=span]",function(){
```

You can also use `dropstart` and `dropend` in place of drop

[Live Drop Demo](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drop/demo/live) With Dynamic Elements